# Boleto bradesco PHP

Tags: php, boleto

Tenho um sistema e utilizo o [Boleto PHP](http://boletophp.com.br/) carteira 25 sem registro do Bradesco, recebi uma ligação do banco falando que essa carteira deixará de existir passando apenas para carteira com Registro.

Eu utilizo o [layout do Boleto PHP](https://github.com/CobreGratis/boletophp/blob/master/include/layout_bradesco.php).

A principal diferença é que no modelo Boleto sem registro o Banco fica sabendo da emissão quando seu cliente efetuar o pagamento, já na cobrança "Registrada" o banco tem conhecimento no momento que você emitir o boleto.

Alguém sabe informar como é feito esse layout ou posso continuar usando o layout do BoletoPHP? Acho que o layout do BoletoPHP é apenas para carteira sem registro pois com registro tenho que enviar uma remessa para o banco no momento que o boleto é gerado. Esse é meu problema, essa bendita remessa.

Comment: Acredito que não poderá continuar a utilizar, no Git fica claro, olha -> https://github.com/CobreGratis/boletophp

Comment: Olá Kleber. Conseguiu resolver? Estou no mesmo dilema que você hoje. Usava o boleto PHP, mas agora preciso implementar o boleto com registro, mas não sei como fazer. Se você conseguiu, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: olá @Fox.11 eu continuei usando o boleto php, porém fiz o arquivo de remessa para enviar ao banco.

Comment: Olá Kleber. Certo. Mas você mudou a carteira ou algo assim? Pergunto porque vou usar o Boleto PHP e gostaria de saber quais as alterações devo fazer para que ele se torne registrado.

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia, 
Em primeiro lugar o banco normalmente oferece um manual de integração do sistema e também como deve ser o layout do ARQUIVO DE REMESSA, é esse o nome do arquivo que conterá as informacões do boleto ou dos boletos que você gera.

trata-se de um arquivo de texto simples, sem formatação que deve seguir padrões que o banco precis, normalmente regulado pela Febraban.

neste arquivo conterá informações como,valor do boleto, nosso número, vencimento e etc dos boletos que se deseja enviar.

O banco fornece um canal de comunicação semelhante ao que existe com a Secretaria da Fazenda onde é possível submeter esse arquivo.

Para não haver a tarefa enfadonha de se enviar esse arquivo de remessa toda vez que gerar um boleto é interessante que haja uma rotina para que antes do fim do expediente comercial seja enviada uma única remessa desse arquivo para o banco contendo todos os boletos emitidos durante o expediente, mas isso é relativo ao processo adotado na empresa.

isso foi uma explicação bem superficial, em resumo o gerente do seu cliente conseguirá esses manuais para vc fazer de acordo com o que estabelece o Bradesco.

Forte abraço

Answer (score 2):

Acontece que no novo sistema, que entrará em vigor em 2017, todos os boletos serão registrados em uma base de dados única, compartilhada com todos os bancos. Onde o boleto só poderá ser pago se ele já estiver registrado nessa base de dados. Dessa forma, será imperativo enviar o arquivo remessa antes mesmo de exibir o boleto para o cliente.

O fluxo novo será assim:

1. Cliente realiza a compra
2. O layout do boleto é gerado
3. O boleto é registrado no banco (conexão similar às transações de cartão de crédito)
4. O boleto é entregue/exibido ao cliente
5. O cliente realiza o pagamento

Se não realizar o passo 3, o cliente pode até receber o boleto, mas não vai conseguir pagá-lo.

Comment: Mesmo que entre em vigor somente em 2017, nesse ano o boleto tem que mudar. Tem que ser com registro, o que não tem necessidade esse ano é o arquivo de remessa, mas ano que vem é obrigatório.